# Unable to remove on-premise database from Azure Sync Group

Tags: synchronization, azure-sql-database

The on-prem database within the Sql Data Sync software is at status 'reachable'. I submit an agent key obtained from the portal, in which test is successful, then click Unregister for one of the databases. I click Yes I'm sure, and presented with this error:

[image]

How do I unregister databases?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason seems to be that you can't unregister a database when it's still involved in sync setup, as seen below:

[image]

Go into the sync group and Delete it first.

[image]